# Android ListView is not showing anything?

Tags: android

```
public class EpisodeScreen extends Activity implements   OnClickListener,OnItemClickListener,IServerResponse {

private String image;
private String episodediscription;
private String video;
private ListView episodelist=null;

private ArrayList<Object> _EpisodeList=new ArrayList<Object>();
private EpisodeAdapter mAdapter=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.episode_list);

    episodelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    episodelist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.play:
        Log.i("click","sucess");

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    getEpisode();
}
public void getEpisode() {
    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(EpisodeScreen.this)) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("issue_id","1"));

        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse(
                (IServerResponse) EpisodeScreen.this);
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(
                Constant.showDialog, this, WebServiceConstants.getMethodUrl(WebServiceConstants.METHOD_NAME_GET_EPISODE_DETAILS),
                EpisodeScreen.this, Constant.PID_EPISODE, false,
                requestParaList);
    } else {
        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.errorTitle,
                Constant.MSG_CHECK_INTERNET_SETTING,
                EpisodeScreen.this, false);

    }
}
@Override
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = response;
    msg.arg1 = processid;
    _handler.sendMessage(msg);
}


private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String respons=msg.obj.toString();
        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case Constant.PID_EPISODE:
            if(respons!=null ){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
                    JSONArray jArray=jsonObj.optJSONArray("Episode Detail");    
                    if(jArray!=null){
                        for(int i =0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            episodebean bean=new episodebean();
                            bean.setEpisode_image(jsonObject.getString("Episode-image"));
                            bean.setEpisode_discription(jsonObject.getString("Episode-description"));
                            bean.setEpisode_video(jsonObject.getString("Episode-video"));
                            _EpisodeList.add(bean);
                        }
                        mAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(EpisodeScreen.this, _EpisodeList);
                        episodelist.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                        /**/
                        /*if(_EpisodeList.size()!=0){
                                mAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(EpisodeScreen.this, _EpisodeList);
                                episodelist.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            }*/
                    }
                }


                catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok........", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
   }
```

here is adapter

```
   public class EpisodeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater _mInflater = null;
private ArrayList<Object> _EpisodeList=null;
private Context ctx = null;

private UserImageLoaderWithCache imageLoader=null;

public EpisodeAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<Object> _episodeList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ctx = context;
    this._EpisodeList = _episodeList;

    imageLoader=new UserImageLoaderWithCache(context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _EpisodeList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _EpisodeList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
static class ViewHolder {


    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView pic;
    public TextView tvurl;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = linf.inflate(R.layout.episode_screen, null);


        // view.imgViewFlag.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_episode);
        holder.tvurl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url);
        holder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_episode);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final episodebean bean=(episodebean)_EpisodeList.get(position);
    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getEpisode_discription());
    holder.tvurl.setText(bean.getEpisode_video());
    imageLoader.display(bean.getEpisode_image(), holder.pic, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return convertView;
}}
```

I am using ListView in which I have to show data, which is coming from server. My ListView is not showing anything while response is coming (although it is showing in logcat) What do I do? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: i think its issue of your adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan my adapter is also in code

Comment: @DigveshPatel sir my adapter is below onitemclick..

Comment: plz log data above return convertview; have you get something??

Comment: On the EpisodeScreen where exactly do you bind the adapter to your listview?

Comment: @DigveshPatel no sir.., i use log..,wait..:0

Comment: @GeorgeD yes is ri have used setadapter for this

Comment: @DigveshPatel no sir value is not showing in log

Comment: @DigveshPatel sir data is not showing in logcat.....

Comment: Must check that are you getting right response and also check that data perfectly comes from server.

Comment: plz check your response and print in logcat

Comment: does you sure that your adapter getCount() method returns more than 0?

Comment: @rajshree have you debugged your handler?? I think your `arraylist` is not being filled. And your adapter code is looking okay.

Comment: @user3110424 its working..,actully it was server side probelm..,response was wrong..,thnku...:)

Answer (score 0):

try to change some code on your adapter at method: getItemId

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

let us know if this work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be help u..replace your handler

```
private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (id) {
}
}
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```